# Java change comparison

Tags: java, comparison, boolean

Is it possible to assign some kind of variable that value of it would change the condition of a comparison? I would like dynamicly change the condition so that it would be required for the comparison not to be true for the condition to be satisfied.

I have a comparison in java like this `if(Table[j]<m)` I would like to dynamicly change the condition, so that it would be like `if(!Table[j]<m)`

Comment: umm can you post a sample and expected output?

Comment: What are you comparing? What are the types?

Comment: You could make a stateful class `Comaparator` with instance `comp` so that `comp.compare(Table[j], m)` gives a value depending on the internal state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like?

```
// requiredCondition can be set dynamically.
if(Table[j] < m == requiredCondition)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that can be configurable at runtime.